# How do you tweet multiple UITextField with TWTweetComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, ios5

I'm trying to use **TWTweetComposeViewController** to do a simple tweet from iOS 5. It works if there is one text field, but how do you create a string of text from 3 UITextFields?

Here is the header text:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *theWorld;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *isGreen;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *andBeautiful;
```

And the implementation:

```
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:
     theWorld.text];

    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
}
```

Notice I only have one text field at the moment and it tweets that input text. I have no idea how tweet all 3 values from the UITextField at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `+stringWithFormat:` method of `NSString`, passing in the values from your three text fields:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", 
                           theWorld.text, isGreen.text, andBeautiful.text];
[tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
```